# Android OKHttp "retry" many times when 401

Tags: android, okhttp, http-status-code-401

I use `OKHttp` to do http request. But when I get a 401 error,it retry many times.

I debugged, found that, when run after the code in `okio.java`[code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2hyn.png), I get 7 requests,[fiddler catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEfA4.png) I only need the first one.

I have used `OkHttpClient.setAuthenticator()` and `return null`

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you isolate the problem into a test case & submit that to OkHttp’s issues tracker? You should start with CallTest.java for example tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
okHttpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(false);
```

Comment: I solve it.Fiddler make it.Close fiddler ,it is OK.Thanks